# Dev Eco Studio Build error : mirrors.tools.huawei.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

[image]

I used the VCS option to import a harmonyOs project from gitee to my Dev Eco Studio and the build failed due to the above errors , please help me resolve it

Gitee(link of the repo which i was trying to open):
https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/EasyPrefs

Comment: hi@ajith m, Could you please share more details about the error info, DevEco Studio version, SDK version？You could also directly submit an issue in the Gitee.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Project from Version Control in File ->New to import the project at the link https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/EasyPrefs in DevEco Studio Release 2.1 Build Version 2.1.0.501, or downloading the project and opening it in the DevEco Studio release version, I can successfully sync the project with Gradle files and build the debug Hap as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

You need to add the “installationFree”: false in the config.json file as shown below.

[image]